# Unable to find and click on the list element in protractor

Tags: protractor

The following is my code snippet. I am not able to find and click on the list element. First I search for a name and the search list is displayed from which I have to select a list element.

```
*` <ul class="results" _ngcontent-c6="">
    <li _ngcontent-c6="">
    <a _ngcontent-c6="">Swati-testing</a>
    </li>
    <li _ngcontent-c6="">
    <a _ngcontent-c6="">Swati-dev</a>
    </li>`*`
```

If I am using element.all, getting an error as element.all is not a function.

Comment: Are the backticks and asterisks part of the code you are trying to show? They seem to have been removed by a contributor once already, but you've added them back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved I have used the below code:

```
element(by.className('results')).all(By.tagName('a')).get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want to click on the list element? Or on the a element?

For "a" element:

```
findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Swati-testing')]"));
```

For "list" element:

```
findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Swati-testing')]/.."));
```

Any should work

Comment: It is recommended to not use xpath

Comment: Could you tell me why exactly not? Sure, xpath is slower than other identiefiers, but a relative xpath is an excellent way to locate elements. Especially when you have your element type noted in it

Comment: Hi ,I want to click on the "a" element. But is there any other way other than the xpath?

Comment: For some situations, xpath or css selector is the best way to go. The xpath I noted above is quite a specific xpath. As the element contains no unique identifier, it is best practise to use xpath or css selector.

Comment: @Anand It's in the [Protractor Style Guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide) - "NEVER use xpath", and it lists several reasons